# How to randomly choose something from a list then remove it while in a function

Tags: python, list, random

```py
from random import choice
from random import choices
from random import shuffle

wkd = ["Razvan", "Vali", "Stefan", "Dontu","Abel", "David P.", "Beni N."]

cls = ["Angelo", "Dragos", "Beni D.", "Andy", "Vlad T.", "Dani", "Ruben", "George", "Sebi Br."]

restul = ["Claudiu", "Cipri", "David", "Rares N.", "Vlad P.", "Marian", "Seba", "Emi", "Darius", "Stefano", "Iosif", "Radu", "Rares", "Robert", "Alberto B.", "David B.", "Robert T."," James", ]

Duminica = "Duminica"
Luni = "Luni"
Marti = "Marti"
Miercuri = "Miercuri"
Joi = "Joi"
Vineri = "Vineri"
def choice_restul():
    global restul
    restul1 = choice(restul)
    restul.remove(restul1)
    return restul1
def choice_restul_wkd():
    global wkd
    global restul
    restul_wkd = str(choice(restul + wkd))
    nr = 1
    try:
        restul.remove(restul_wkd)
        wkd.remove(restul_wkd)
    except ValueError:
        nr += 1
        
    return restul_wkd
def choice_toti():
    global restul
    global wkd
    global cls
    choice_toti = str(choice(restul + wkd + cls))
    nr = 1
    try:
        restul.remove(choice_toti)
        wkd.remove(choice_toti)
        cls.remove(choice_toti)
    except ValueError:
        nr += 1
class servicii:
    def cantina():
        nr_sapt = 1
        while nr_sapt < 5:
            with open(f'cantina{nr_sapt}.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write("Cantina")
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Duminica + "" + "-" + choice_restul()) 
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Luni + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd()) 
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Marti + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Miercuri + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Joi + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(Vineri + "" + "-" + choice_restul())
                f.write("\n")
            nr_sapt += 1
        return "Cantina"
    def palier():
        with open('rezultat.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("Palier")
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Duminica + "" + "-" + choice_restul()) 
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Luni + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd()) 
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Marti + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Miercuri + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Joi + "" + "-" + choice_restul_wkd())
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(Vineri + "" + "-" + choice_restul())
            f.write("\n")
        return "Palier"
    def curte():
        curte = "curte"
        return curte
    def poarta():
        poarta = "poarta"
        return poarta

print(servicii.cantina())
```

This is my code. It's in another language but basically what I want to do is randomly choose someone from a list to do certain tasks but I don't want someone to be picked again. I did something to remove from the list once picked but it isn't working. The same person is picked again. Can somebody help?

I tried everything (I think) I want to remove someone from the list once picked, but the remove is only local but I want it to be globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your random choice, you pick from the sum of lists (which is ok). When you come to remove the chosen item, you catch errors, which then may mask the actual removal. You probably need a function which tried each container in turn:

```py
def remove_element(containers, element):
    for c in containers:
        try:
            c.remove(element)
            return
        except ValueError:
            pass

def choice_restul_wkd():
    global wkd
    global restul
    restul_wkd = choice(restul + wkd)
    remove_element([restul, wkd], restul_wkd)
        
    return restul_wkd
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this but I'm also a beginner  well now it works.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Index error.... How do i solve it?

Comment: Ask a new question here on stackoverflow. Include the relevant code and the full error traceback.